# I can't get it to display the updated temperature

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make it so that if the user chooses 1, it should increase the temp by 5, and decrease if the user chooses 2. the problem I'm having is that it doesn't update the value of the temperature.

UPDATE: I've finally got the math part to work but for some reason when i print the value of temperature it doesn't save the updates. If i do warmer, it's always at 20 and if i do cooler it's always at 10. I'm guessing i have to use the getTemp() because im only editing the local variable? How do I go about this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class heater 
{
public:
    int temperature;
    int min;
    int max;
    int increment;
    heater(int min=0, int max=60)
    {
        increment = 5;
        temperature = 15;
    }
    
    int warmer(int);
    int cooler(int);
    int getTemp(int);
    
};

int heater::warmer(int temperature) {
    if (temperature > (temperature - increment))
    {
        temperature += increment;
        return temperature;
    }
    else cout << "Max temp reached.";
}

int heater::cooler(int temperature) {
    if (temperature < (temperature + increment)){
        temperature -= increment;
        return temperature;
    }
    else cout << "Min temp reached.";
}

int heater::getTemp(int temperature) {
   return temperature;
}

int main()
{
    heater w;
    heater c;
    heater t;
    heater g;
    int i;
    int number;
    int temp;
    for (i = 1; i != 0; i=1)
    {
        cout << "\n1. Warmer \n";
        cout << "2. Cooler \n";
        cout << "Press 0 to exit. \n";
        cin >> number;
        if (number == 1) {
            temp = w.warmer(t.temperature);
            cout << "The temperature is now: " << temp;
        }
        else if (number == 2) {
            temp = c.cooler(t.temperature);
            cout << "The temperature is now: " << temp;
        }
        else if (number == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int heater::warmer(int temperature)` and `int heater::cooler(int temperature)` modify only the local variable `temperature`, not the member variable. You probably meant to use `this->temperature`. But why does it take any parameters at all? And why is it marked to return something when there is no need to? Not sure if this is intended.

Comment: Or remove the parameter, since you increase/decrease by a constant amount anyway. BTW, did your compiler not complain that you are shadowing the member variable with the parameter?

Comment: Please note that you still have shadowing declaration in your constructor (`min` & `max`). If you have to specify the type (here: `int`), it is usually because you are creating a brand new variable, and therefore cannot easily access the one in the higher scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `int heater::warmer(int temperature)` parameter named `temperature` shadows class member called `temperature` and you only modify that local parameter.

Simply remove that parameters and modify your class member:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class heater 
{
public:
    int temperature;
    heater()
    {
        temperature = 15;
    }
    
    int warmer();
    int cooler();
    int getTemp();
    
};

int heater::warmer() {
   temperature -= 5;
}

int heater::cooler() {
   temperature += 5;
}

int heater::getTemp() {
   return temperature;
}

int main()
{
    heater w;
    heater c;
    heater t;
    int number;
    cout << "1. Warmer \n";
    cout << "2. Cooler \n";
    cin >> number;
    if (number == 1) {
        w.warmer();
        cout << "The temperature is now: " << t.temperature;
    }
    else if (number == 2) {
        c.cooler();
        cout << "The temperature is now: " << t.temperature;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also, the line `heater getTemp();` doesn't do anything useful. It declares a global function that returns `heater` and takes no parameters. You probably wanted to call the member function like this:

```
        cout << "The temperature is now: " << t.getTemp();
```

Comment: I've finally got the math part to work but for some reason when i print the value of temperature it doesn't save the updates. If i do warmer, it's always at 20 and if i do cooler it's always at 10. I'm guessing i have to use the getTemp() because im only editing the local variable? How do I go about this?

Comment: I updated the code to my most recent progress as well

Comment: @BlaneGador Check your implementations then ;) `warmer()` lowers the temperature and `colder()` makes it higher. It's a typo.

Comment: oh yes i fixed that but for instance when I choose warmer and it goes up to 20, the loop brings the menu back and when i press warmer again, it' still at 20; im assuming its because it doesnt save the value so it goes back to the initial value of 15. How do I make it so that it saves the vlue?

Comment: @BlaneGador You have not fixed the issue I pointed in my answer. You should remove parameters that are passed to `warmer()` and `cooler()`, because they shadow your member variable and that member variable is not updated.

Comment: I have finally got it to work, thank you very much for your help and patience :)

Comment: @BlaneGador No problem, glad I could help :)